# sharepoint upload attachment, save conflict error

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sharepoint

I get a 'save conflict' error when trying to upload multiple attachments to my list, and from what I understand, it's because sharepoint is still processing the last attachment when a new one comes in.

What I believe could help is some sort of delay before sending in the next file, but this could also fail if said file is very big (the delay is too short).

This is how I am uploading attachments at the moment:

Using promises, `$q`

```
var elementPromises = [];
angular.forEach(element.files, function(item){

  item = $scope.UploadAttachment(item).then(function(){});
  elementPromises.push(item);
});

$q.all(elementPromises).then(function () {
  // alert('all attachments saved');

}, function(reason) {
  // alert('Failed: ' + reason);

}, function(update) {
  //alert('Got notification: ' + update);
});
```

UploadAttachment function:

```
  $scope.UploadAttachment = function(file){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    setTimeout(function() {
       // deferred.notify('Saving attachments..');
        readFile(file).done(function (buffer, fileName) {
            var saveFile = new Entry(buffer);
            saveFile.$upload({ID: ID, filename: fileName}, function(u){
                console.log(u);
                deferred.resolve('Success');
            }, function(error){
                console.log(error);
                deferred.reject('Error');
            });
        });
    }, 1000);
    return deferred.promise;
};
```

`ReadFile` is a filereader function, from wich I get a buffer and filename, this is what I upload to `SharePoint`.

`Entry` in `New Entry (buffer)` is a `$resource` factory, and has this `$upload` function:

```
      upload: {
        url: "serverURL/_api/lists/getByTitle('listName')/items(:ID)/AttachmentFiles/add(FileName=':filename')",
        method: "POST",
        transformRequest: [],
        processData: true,
        headers: {
            "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
            "X-RequestDigest": function() {return  $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()},
            "content-length": function () {
                return arguments[0].data.byteLength;
            }
        }
    }
```

As I said, this works perfectly for one file (or a few small ones), but when trying to upload multiple files with some size on them, I run into the save conflict error.

My only idea so far is some kind of delay, but I don't know where or how to implement it, also I am afraid that won't be enough, any thoughts on this?

Answer (score 0):

You need to serialize item update and item file attachment REST calls. The next call must not fire before the previous one has completed. With your implementation calls happen in parallel, causing the save conflict.